# Why does the Classifier of an embedded RequiredInterface on a Component instance in Enterprise Architect changes after it is being renamed?

Tags: enterprise-architect

I observed a behaviour in Enterprise Architect while working with `Component`s and `RequiredInterface`s that I cannot explain and am looking for an explanation.

## Here is the case:

1. I have an `Interface` *Interface1-a6a8ab9f-11f4-4277-a2dc-dd4948ffc36d* (see figure 1).
2. I have a `Component` *Component1-234e39eb-78b2-4484-b48a-8c0c52490673* with an `ProvidedInterface` that links to/is classified by *Interface1-a6a8ab9f-11f4-4277-a2dc-dd4948ffc36d* (see figure 2, 9). The `Classifier` of the `ProvidedInterface` references the `Object_ID` **18298** of the `Interface` *Interface1-a6a8ab9f-11f4-4277-a2dc-dd4948ffc36d* (see figure 3).
3. Now when I instantiate the `Component` along with its `ProvidedInterface` the `Classifier` of the newly instantiated `ProvidedInterface` links to the `Object_ID` **18299** of the `ProvidedInterface` as seen in figure 2 (see figure 4). I added a screenshot (see figure 7, 8) that shows, how I created the instance.

## Unexplainable behaviour

So far, so good. However, when I rename the instantiated `ProvidedInterface` (and even rename it back to its original name) via the *Element Properties* dialogue, the `Classifier` of the instantiated `ProvidedInterface` *magically* changes from **18299** to the `Object_ID` **18298** of the original `Interface` (see figure 5 and 6).
The same behaviour occurs when renaming the original `Interface` in the UI or via API/script (but not when renaming other attributes such as the `Alias`).

```js
function main()
{
    var element AS EA.Element;
    element = Repository.GetElementByGuid('{75BB908D-9B1A-4258-8748-9D2E51DCB8FB}');
    Session.Output("element " + element.Name);

    var originalName = element.Name;
    element.Name = "Schnittenfittich";
    element.Update();
    element.Refresh();
    Session.Output("element " + element.Name);

    element.Name = originalName;
    element.Update();
    element.Refresh();
    Session.Output("element " + element.Name);
}

main();
```

## Question

Why does the `Classifier` id change by renaming the `ProvidedInterface` name (or its classifying `Interface`?

## Notes

- There are further inconsistencies on instantiated `ProvidedInterface`s such as the `ea_guid` being displayed as the `ea_guid` of the original `ProvidedInterface` and having that guid being persisted in the `PDATA3` attribute of `t_object`. I am not sure if and how this has to do with it.
- EA version being used is v14.1.1429
- Database is JET/EAP
- This behaviour does not occur in EA v12.5 @Oracle

## Figure 1: Details of `Interface`

[image: Details of Interface *Interface1-a6a8ab9f-11f4-4277-a2dc-dd4948ffc36d*]

## Figure 2: `Component` and `ProvidedInterface`

[image: Component and ProvidedInterface]

## Figure 3: Details of `ProvidedInterface`

[image: Details of <code>ProvidedInterface</code>]

## Figure 4: Details of instantiated `ProvidedInterface`

[image: Details of instantiated <code>ProvidedInterface</code>]

## Figure 5: `ProvidedInterface` with new `Name`

[image: <code>ProvidedInterface</code> with new <code>Name</code>]

## Figure 6: New `Classifier` on instantiated `ProvidedInterface`

[image: New <code>Classifier</code> on instantiated <code>ProvidedInterface</code>]

## Figure 7: Creation of instantiated `Component` and `ProvidedInterface`

[image: Creation of instantiated <code>Component</code> and <code>ProvidedInterface</code>]

## Figure 8: Instantiated `Provided Interface` has `Classifier`

[image: Instantiated <code>Provided Interface</code> has <code>Classifier</code>]

## Figure 9: Selecting classifier for Provided Interface

[image: Selecting classifier for Provided Interface]

Comment: I struggled creating the base. When I instantiate a component with PI the instance's PI is not classified.

Comment: @qwerty_so I added figure 7 to show how I create the instance, if that helps

Comment: I see that you use copy instead of dragging from browser. That gives another ton of EA options. I tried Paste as New on a diagram. But that only created the component without the embedded iface. Your EA version (I'm on 13.5 but can test 14 too)?

Comment: I am not copying the element but really dragging it from the project browser so that the "Paste ..." dialogue appears.

Comment: EA version as in the Notes section: 14.1.1429

Comment: I'm working top down your question. EA is not helpful in its GUI. I suppose you drag/drop as instance. When I do that my instance's RI has no parent (classifier). Maybe you have some magic MDG turned on?

Comment: correct, I drag/drop the component from the project browser as an instance (as shown in the screenshot). I currently do not have any EA v13 to test it; but I can test it on a v12.5 tomorrow. Then we might see if this *feature* was introduced on v14 ... I added another image where you can see that my instance PI is really having a classifier. Regarding your previous comment where you mentioned you have issues create the *base*. Did you there select the interface via the `Select Interface` box?

Comment: I used V14 to test the above. Rather look for your MDG settings.

Comment: I disabled all add-ins via "Specialise, Add-Ins, Manage", restarted and still have the same effect.

Comment: Ah, now I'm getting to it. I used Advanced/Parent, not dbl-click. Oh well...

Answer (score 1):

Well, EA is strange in many respects. Here's what I created:

[image]

The component #2066 containing the PI #2068 and the interface #2070 were created first. Then I assigned (dbl-click) the classifier #2070 to the PI #2068.

Next I created a new instance of component #2066 which got the id #2071 (you see it's classified with the first #2066). The embedded RI #2072 has the classifier #2068 which is the PI of the original component. It does not assign the classifier that one got (#2070) but from where it was copied.

So: your assumption that the instance's RI is also classified the same as its origin is wrong. It's classified with its parent RI (like the component is with its parent).

---

Next: renaming th RI. I just used the properties window to rename:

[image]

and that results in

[image]

huuuu? What's this. Not only both now have the same classifier (#2070 the interface). Now *both* RIs are renamed?!

[image]

Now, if that isn't a bug I don't know. Will it be fixed? I don't know either but my guess would be: not too soon.

---

Some more testing. I added a new interface `abc` and in the IR-dbl-click dialog entered plainly "abc". This did set the classifier in the database to #0 while the name "abc" was kept. (Using the properties dialog had the same effect). Using the ellipsis to choose `abc` in contrast did set the proper classifier ID. You can't choose that from the properties window, though. Ah, I forgot: it's EA.

Further when changing the RI name of the parent component this also changed the name of the RI of the instance.

---

To say this is weird is more than an understatement.

Feel free to send bug reports to Sparx. But it's probably better to have a beer and think for some other solution.

Comment: I'll look into that renaming "feature" tomorrow :-)

Comment: so this is exactly the same behaviour as I described in the question. looks more and more like a bug - I agree. Thanks for the confirmation, but the reason for it still seems to be unknown. thanks anyway!

Comment: The reason is simple: it's EA.